# How to pass an object in lua to json, with php?

Tags: php, lua

I have several .lua files that have this structure, how could I pass this to json using php?

```
local monster = {}

monster.description = "a toad"
monster.experience = 60
monster.outfit = {
    lookType = 222,
    lookHead = 0,
    lookBody = 0,
    lookLegs = 0,
    lookFeet = 0,
    lookAddons = 0,
    lookMount = 0
}

monster.raceId = 262
monster.Bestiary = {
    class = "Amphibic",
    race = BESTY_RACE_AMPHIBIC,
    toKill = 500,
    FirstUnlock = 25,
    SecondUnlock = 250,
    CharmsPoints = 15,
    Stars = 2,
    Occurrence = 0,
    Locations = "The Laguna Islands, Arena and Zoo Quarter, Tiquanda/Tarantula Caves, \z
        Shadowthorn Bog God Temple, Northern Zao Plantations, Northern Brimstone Bug Cave."
    }

monster.health = 135
monster.maxHealth = 135

monster.changeTarget = {
    interval = 4000,
    chance = 10
}

monster.voices = {
    interval = 5000,
    chance = 10,
    {text = "Ribbit! Ribbit!", yell = false},
    {text = "Ribbit!", yell = false}
}

monster.loot = {
    {name = "gold coin", chance = 80000, maxCount = 20},
    {name = "war hammer", chance = 148},
    {name = "mace", chance = 2854},
    {id = 3578, chance = 20000},
    {name = "poisonous slime", chance = 4761}
}

monster.attacks = {
    {name ="melee", interval = 2000, chance = 100, minDamage = 0, maxDamage = -30, effect = CONST_ME_DRAWBLOOD, condition = {type = CONDITION_POISON, totalDamage = 20, interval = 4000}},
    {name ="combat", interval = 2000, chance = 20, type = COMBAT_PHYSICALDAMAGE, minDamage = -8, maxDamage = -17, range = 7, shootEffect = CONST_ANI_POISON, effect = CONST_ME_GREEN_RINGS, target = false}
}

monster.defenses = {
    defense = 6,
    armor = 6,
    {name ="speed", interval = 2000, chance = 15, speedChange = 200, effect = CONST_ME_MAGIC_RED, target = false, duration = 5000}
}
```

I thought about making a parser class to assemble the structure, because it's not too far from a json structure. Does anyone have something in mind or can extract this data?

Comment: use a lib? https://github.com/rxi/json.lua

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library such as [lunajson](https://github.com/grafi-tt/lunajson/) to convert a Lua value, in your case a table, to a JSON string.

To extract the data, you can simply execute the files - for example using `loadfile` - and then get the value of the variable:

- If the variable is global, simply indexing the global table;
- If the variable is local - as in your example - you either need to add `return var` to the end of your script (if it isn't already there) or use Lua's builtin `debug` library to extract it.

Your code strikes me as somewhat odd because the local variable is not exported (and the code would thus be a no-op).

If you are concerned with security, simply set an empty environment for the files to ensure that they can't call any functions. You can further clear the string metatable if you don't want string functions to be callable.

Putting it all together (using Lua 5.1, which provides `setfenv` to set a function environment) and assuming the file ends with `return monster`:

```lua
local lunajson = require"lunajson"
local path_to_file = ...
local chunk = assert(loadfile(path_to_file))
setfenv(chunk, {}) -- set empty environment
local str_mt = getmetatable""
local str_mt_idx = str_mt.__index
str_mt.__index = nil
local status, val_or_err = pcall(chunk) -- execute file
str_mt.__index = str_mt_idx
if not status then error(val_or_err) end -- error after restoring the string metatable
print(lunajson.encode(val_or_err)) -- print the encoded JSON
```

You can now use this as a shell utility: `lua5.1 myutil.lua file_to_convert.lua >> output.json`

Comment: Exceptions in `chunk()` will be propagated, unlike your expectation of `nil, errmes` result.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff forgot to type the `pcall`